# Nested for-loops stalling program?

Tags: for-loop, processing, freeze, processing.js

*Code Updated 1/26*

So I came up with a problem for my students that seemed simple in theory. A little embarrassingly, however, I cannot create a *working* solution for it.
So, I've done some extensive troubleshooting and research and I think I've found the hang-up, but not how to get around it.

We are using ProcessingJS. It seems that in any situation where I have a for-loop running through an array *inside* another for-loop searching through a different array, my program hangs up. It doesn't crash, it just... doesn't do anything. It creates a window that doesn't do anything.
The task is to create a program that looks at the documents of a file and identify how many instances each letter and character there are.
My code has nested for-loops. The first loop goes through the contents of the first line in my file. The second loops uses the result of the first loop and looks through an array to see if any 'instances' of that letter have already been found. If it has not been found, it appends it. If an instance of the letter HAS been found, then it increases the number value found in a second array.
The contents of the file are 4 lines, each line containing hundreds of words separated by commas.
Here's my code:

```java
//!!!!!!!!!!Declare Variables!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

String exampleTXT[] = loadStrings("sounds.txt");

//String [][] results = {{"null", "null"}};

String [] resultsAlpha = {"null"};
int[] resultsNumber = {0};

boolean analyze = true;


//
//!!!!!!!!!!!Void Setup!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//
void setup() {
  println("hey 1");    
  size(800, 800);
  println("hey 2");
}
//!!!!!!!!!!!End of Void Setup!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//


//
//!!!!!!!!!!!Void Draw!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//
//
//
void draw() {
  println("hey 3");
  background(0);
  println("hey 4");
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  println("hey 5");
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP);
  println("hey 6");

  //nothing to see on this line

  println("hey 7");
  if (analyze == true) {
    println("hey 8");
    for (int i = 0; i < exampleTXT[0].length(); i++) {
      println("hey 9");        
      for ( int r = 0; r < resultsAlpha.length(); r++) {
        println("hey 10");          
        if (exampleTXT[0][i] != resultsAlpha[r]) {
          println("hey 11");           
          resultsAlpha = append(resultsAlpha, exampleTXT[0][i]);
          println("hey 12");          
          resultsNumber = append(resultsNumber, 0);
          println("hey 13");
        }
        println("hey 14");       
        if ( exampleTXT[0][i] == resultsAlpha[r]) {
          println("hey 15");       
          resultsNumber[r]++;
          println("hey 16");
        }
        println("hey 17");
      }
      println("hey 18");
    }
    println("hey 19");       
    analyze = false;
    println("hey 20");
  }
  println("hey 21");       


  for (int i = 0; i<resultsAlpha.length(); i++) {
    println("hey 22"); 
    text(resultsAlpha[i] + " " + resultsNumber[i], 0, 10*i);
    println("hey 23");
  }
  println("hey 24"); 
  if (frameCount%60==0) {
    println("hey 25"); 
    println(frameCount / 60);
    println("hey 26");
  }
  println("hey 27");
}
//!!!!!!!!!!!End of Void Draw!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//


//
//!!!!!!!!!!!Void KeyPressed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//
//
//
void keyPressed() {

  if (key == DELETE) {
    println(exampleTXT[0]);
  }
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    println(resultsNumber);
  }

  //
  // Break your code up into logical sections with comments!
  //
}

//!!!!!!!!  End of Void keyPressed  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

So that's what I'm working with. I am wondering if maybe I am running into some sort of memory issue when trying to do this. I'm not sure, though, because that seems like it wouldn't impact the system that hard, but I frankly don't have any other reasoning.

The one answer provided so far was for another version of code. With that helpful advice I was able to get that to work, but the problem with this code still remains :(

Can anyone explain what my issue is?

Comment: I have tried commenting out different parts. So first I tried to comment out the entirety of the for-loops. That caused my program to work. Then I started re-introducing pieces. The first for-loop when reintroduced worked fine. It wasn't until I uncommented the second for-loop that things broke :(
So I wonder i something is broken with the for-loop itself, or if simply looking through an array and using that data to look through another array is too much for processingJS?

Answer (score 3):

`for (int r = 0; r < numbers.length; i++){`

You are incrementing i instead of r in this loop.

Comment: Ah... well.. about that... ummm...

I'm an idiot. Thank you! :)